# Nginx config re-usable blocks

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have Nginx configured as a reverse proxy for some application servers like so, but there is a lot of duplicate code there (with the exception of the proxy_pass line). Is there any way I can move the proxy_redirect and proxy_set_header lines into some common block and just reference that for each location block?

Nginx.conf:

```
location ^~ /users {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:5001;
            proxy_redirect http://api.example.com https://api.example.com;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}

location ^~ /users/verify {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:5002;
            proxy_redirect http://api.example.com https://api.example.com;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can do this in your `http` block of your config like so:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format    main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #Rest of your config

    #Proxy settings
    proxy_redirect http://api.example.com https://api.example.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Note that these settings would be "global".